# Python: Good place to learn about `multiprocessing.Manager`?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to learn to use `multiprocessing.Manager`. I looked at the documentation but it's not easy enough for me. Anyone knows of a good tutorial or something like that?

Comment: If you don't get any joy on the request for a tutorial, try elaborating on your question with some specific parts that you don't understand. Is there a code snippet that you've tried that isn't working? Is there a particular concept that's inscrutable?

Comment: No, thanks for trying to help, but I just want an introduction to Managers.

Comment: i'm totally with RR on this. just a few real world (not the connect, send-hi-msg, receive-hi-msg) examples and some explanation on how this works. I'm also searching for a decent description/manual. Not that I have specific problem to solve, just want to find out how it all fits together and some use cases/patterns.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation of multiprocessing.Manager](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) contains extensive examples for using a Manager and the various objects associated with the calss:

> Managers provide a way to create data
>   which can be shared between different
>   processes. A manager object controls a
>   server process which manages shared
>   objects. Other processes can access
>   the shared objects by using proxies.
>   [and so on]

Manager objects allow you to create variables shared in multiple processes. What is it that you **exactly** want to achieve? Maybe a request for an example would help?

Comment: I also think the standard docs are quite illustrative, but isn't a tutorial, like he's seeking, basically a request for an example? :-)

Comment: Well, I think that in the Pycon talk it was said that Managers can manage pools for you, also on remote computers. So I'd like a gentle introduction to that, if one exists.

Comment: Despite the above comments, there are examples of everything related to Multiprocessing within those docs.

Comment: The standard docs it's not so clear and understandable, I find it not enough to learn how to use Manager in Python.